# "Hello World" program not functioning on Windows PE post Visual Studio Update

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Prior to updating Microsoft Visual Studio (from 15.?.? to 15.8.6) there was no issue compiling and transferring over to Windows PE.

Since updating, some of my older programs still compile and then operate, but my most recent ones do not.

In order to test whether this was caused by an issue in my code, I created a very simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

The program is compiled as follows:

- In 64 bits
- As a release version
- On /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
- With pre-compilation disabled

This program should output "Hello World!" but instead outputs a blank line before reverting to console input.

This is not a failure solely related to std::cout; I have also tested with printf(), as well as requesting input with getchar() and std::cin. In all of these cases, there was no output and it did not wait for input.

I have also taken the following steps to ensure that the issue is a general one, and not related to a specific failure of my VS installation or testing environment:

- I wrote and compiled a similar program (but with pre-compilation enabled) on a separate machine, with its own VS Installation. The issue re-occurred with that compilation.
- I have compared settings for the projects that are working and those that are not, and they appear to be identical.
- I tested the program on a standard Windows 10 installation on a separate computer, where it operated without issue. I then launched Windows PE on that computer, and the program failed again in the above manner.
- I tested the program with a separate copy of Windows PE, and the program failed again in the above manner.

At this point, I am unable to determine what the issue might be. I even disabled Specter Mitigation, in case that was for some reason incompatible with Windows PE, but there was no change.

I assume it is something to do with a change of default settings post-update, but I have been unable to identify the specific setting; I have modified the settings to match those of the older project that still operates but this did not change the test outcome.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you redirect your output to a file? Does the file contains "Hello World"?

Comment: @user1810087 No, the output file is blank.

Comment: Static or Dynamic runtime support?

Comment: @RichardCritten Dynamic. Tested Static, and now it works - I assume that would be because the DLL's the Dynamic was demanding were not available on PE?

Comment: Or it was available but had ABI issues.  You should install the appropriate redist  package if you need to use dynamic runtime support.